# xsl - recursive match on xml using partial string

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have an xml that uses very complicated matrix of id names over a myriad of node.
For Example:
060a2b34.01010101.01010f00.13000000.060e2b34.7f7f2a80.519b69a4.8e8600fc

Unfortunately I have to use a partial name match in my xsl to achieve a match efficiently.

I am hoping someone can help me with the below before I go about creating a question that has full example xsl code and input and expected XML examples.

The Below uses the full string which works:

```
<xsl:when test="name(.)='personA'"><xsl:value-of select="../../../../../../../../../*[self::CompositionPackage]
                                                            [PackageID=current()
                                                            /personA_ID]
                                                            /PackageName"/></xsl:when>
```

And here I am attempting to use a substring using only the first 53 characters which fails on line 3

```
<xsl:when test="name(.)='personA'"><xsl:value-of select="../../../../../../../../../*[self::CompositionPackage]
                                                            [substring(PackageID,1,53)=current()
                                                            /substring(personA_ID,1,53)]
                                                            /PackageName"/>
                                                            </xsl:when>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of `substring(PackageID,1,53)=current()/substring(personA_ID,1,53)` you want `substring(PackageID,1,53) = substring(current()/personA_ID, 1, 53)`.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the quick response, If I use that I get an error "function Substing not found" .

Comment: Performing a test the first substring on line 2 works if i get it to use the full 71 characters in the string. '[substring(PackageID,1,71)=current()' and leave line 3 as in example 1. i still however need the personA_ID substring to match using 53 characters.

Comment: I think you need to show us a sample of the XML and the context if you need more help. The syntax `current()/substring(PersonA_ID, 1, 53)` is possible in XSLT/XPath 2.0 but not in XSLT/XPath 1.0. So that is something we can correct and suggest to be changed based solely on the syntax of the XSLT code presented. Whether the suggested change then compares what you want to compare is hard to tell without seeing the input data.

Comment: Actually This Works, Fat Fingers to blame. Thanks Martin. Your time is most appreciated.